# Hibernate flush() method confusion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I understand that Hibernate's Session.flush() method writes current data state in memory into the database. I use it and it works fine. But my question is: using Session.flush() is mandatory?

If I remove Session.flush() then nothing gets inserted/updated in the database. And I don't see any errors in my log file.

I am using Spring + Hibernate in my application. I am also using the OpenSessionInViewFilter which I have defined in my web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>     
         <param-name>flushMode</param-name>       
         <param-value>AUTO</param-value> 
    </init-param>     
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried using flushMode as COMMIT but still it didn't help.

My Spring applicationContext.xml has the following lines for datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And finally my code snippet looks like this:

```
public String saveRegistration (final Registration registration) {

    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(registration);
    getSession().flush(); // If I remove this, no records would be inserted/updated!!
    String id = registration.getId();

    return id;
}
```

As you can see I am using a very basic configurations in Spring and Hibernate.

Can someone please help me in understanding as to why getSession.flush() should be called? Why without it no records are getting saved/updated in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that no records get created in the database? If you are saying that because the returned id is null then I think you've misunderstood. When you call saveOrUpdate, the object will be stored in the Hibernate session and other code that runs a query can retrieve it, but **it won't necessarily be persisted to the database immediately**. The current object instance won't have an id until you run a query that prompts Hibernate to persist the object to the database, or you manually call flush().

I'd suggest you check what the behaviour is if you code a second method to query for the object. I think you'll find that causes Hibernate to flush the object to the database.

Comment: If you are viewing the table via a separate database tool, that won't cause Hibernate to write the data to the database. What happens if write a second method to query the database?

Comment: Even after querying the same table after the saveRegistration() method completes, I don't see the records getting retrieved. As a matter of fact, if I print all the SQL queries that gets fired by the hibernate I don't see any query that inserts record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably parameter "registration" is not been changed once it's loaded from database or saved.  Hibernate will save/update entity when there is some difference between cached object and database data.

Try after modifying one of the field in "registration" instance.

Also, it would be good idea to turn on Hibernate/Spring debug logging and see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: The registration object is created new every time and then I call the saveRegistration() method. So I am not updating it but I am creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The flush is just synchronization with the db and then you need to commit or clear the session to see the changes.

And if you do just commit .It automatically flushes and you can see your changes from another session too.

### **Commit will make the database commit**

**Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
store with persistable state held in memory.**

ie. it will update or insert into your tables in the running
transaction, but it *may* not commit those changes (this depends on
your flush mode).

Comment: I get that. My original question is whether the usage of Session.flush() method mandatory? As I have said above, if I don't use the flush() method than no record get inserted. I am trying to understand the cause of it.

Comment: Need not if you are using transaction.commit .  inside commit method it will flush ..if you are not using ultimately  you have to call session.flush() .Using transaction is better practice .

Comment: So what I understand is that I have to use transaction.commit() to insert the record in the database? Which implies that by just calling getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(registration) will not get the job done? Does using the transaction.commit() a common practice or I have to do this because something is wrong with my set up?

Comment: No.what i am suggesting is  for better results you have to use transaction .The main thing is transaction have rollback system .you wont acheive that with session.so surround your session with transaction..its the best practise.

Comment: Go through https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Hibernate+Sessions+and+Transaction+Management+Guidelines